# making reddit's buttons asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reddit

I'm trying to add Reddit buttons to my site, but they are not asynchronous, and Reddit tends to lag, slowing down page loads. When I look at what the script returns, I get something like this:

```
(function () {
    var write_string = ...
    document.write(write_string);
})()
```

I try to inject it into my page after a page load. I've tried both these methods in javascript after page load to no avail:

```
placeholder.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=5"></script>'

var js = document.createElement('script');
js.type = 'text/javascript';
js.src = 'http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=5';
placeholder.appendChild(js);
```

where `placeholder` is a DOM element `<div class="reddit-button"></div>`. Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "override" the `document.write` method:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    document.write = function(text) {
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML += text;
    };
    oScript.src = "http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=0";
    document.body.appendChild(oScript);
};
```

This way the external code can call `document.write` as much as it wants to and you push the HTML to the proper place in your document.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NkDvB/) - Tested OK under Chrome, Firefox and IE9 so guess it should be enough.